# WP_Query meta_query >= date

Tags: wp-query, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, date

I have been trying for hours, I don't get my query to work: **display only posts (from custom post type) with a field (Advanced Custom Fields date picker) value that is more than today**.

`echo date('d-m-Y');` prints the same date format as the posts output `the_field('datum_event');` : 06-01-2019

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'agenda',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'datum_event',
            'value'   => '06-01-2019',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

What is missing?

Comment: Try adding `'type' => 'DATE',` to the most inner array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is missing? One tiny detail... And it's easy to overlook...

```
the_field('datum_event');
```

Prints the field using the format you've defined in field settings. But... It has nothing to do with how the value of that field is stored in DB. ACF uses `YYYYMMDD` format when storing date values in DB. And WP_Query doesn't use field format, since it looks directly in DB.

So you have to use other/raw format in your WP_Query:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'agenda',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'datum_event',
            'value'   => '20190106',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Ah that's grand! Now using `'value'   => date('Ymd'),` and it's working!

Comment: Exactly, this is proper date format :)